# Reference object property through variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to reference an object property **without** using Get-Variable.
Anybody know how to do that?

```
$myObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    url                = 'TESTURL'
    webResponse        = ''
}

$objName = 'myObject'

Write-Host Attempt1
(Get-Variable -Name $objName -ValueOnly).url     # this works, yields TESTURL.

Write-Host Attempt2 
$($objName).url    # this fails, $($objName) returns a string instead of an object
```

I was expecting `$($objName)` to return an object, but it returns a string instead.

Comment: Well, of course, $objName is the name of your object. `$myObject.url` should work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$objName` is string, you defined it yourself as a string. What you do with `Get-Variable` is getting a variable which is called `myObject`. The value that you got from `Get-Variable` is the actual variable of correct type. As pointed already, `$myObject.url` will work.

Compare it to let's say word `apple` and the actual fruit

Comment: I know `$myObject.url` will work. But the thing is that I have a number of objects that have an URL property. I also have an array with the object names. I'd like to loop over those names and access the corresponding objects, setting the URL. Preferably without using Get-Variable. Is there no other way?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing `$variable1 = Get-Varable $name1` and then `$variable1.property`

Comment: You can also use an array of vars or a dictionary and loop